# firehol simple config doesn't work on Debian 7

Tags: debian, iptables

I'm trying to set up a very simple firehol setup under a brand new Debian7 server.
I only installed ssh and sudo before this

Installed firehol with

```
sudo apt-get install firehol
```

Changed the config in /etc/firehol/firehol.conf to:

```
#!/sbin/firehol
version 5
interface eth0 y1
        policy drop
        server ICMP accept
        server ssh accept

        client all accept
```

And after I enter

```
firehol try
```

the ssh session was frozen for 30 seconds (lucky me I asked to try only) and there's this output:

> IMPORTANT WARNING:  ------------------  FireHOL cannot find your
>   current kernel configuration.  Please, either compile your kernel with
>   /proc/config,  or make sure there is a valid kernel config in: 
>   /usr/src/linux/.config
>
> Because of this, FireHOL will simply attempt to load  all kernel
>   modules for the services used, without  being able to detect failures.
>
> FireHOL: Saving your old firewall to a temporary file: OK FireHOL:
>   Processing file /etc/firehol/firehol.conf: OK FireHOL: Activating new
>   firewall (53 rules):
>
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- WARNING : This might or might not affect the operation of your
>   firewall. WHAT    : A runtime command failed to execute (returned
>   error 1). SOURCE  : line FIN of /etc/firehol/firehol.conf COMMAND :
>   /sbin/modprobe ip_conntrack_irc -q OUTPUT  :
>
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- WARNING : This might or might not affect the operation of your
>   firewall. WHAT    : A runtime command failed to execute (returned
>   error 1). SOURCE  : line FIN of /etc/firehol/firehol.conf COMMAND :
>   /sbin/modprobe ip_conntrack_ftp -q OUTPUT  :

I installed a firehol in another very similar server and never got an issue

Comment: Is your server or a physical machine or a VM?  Some VPS technologies don't give you a kernel that can do firewalling/nat in the guest.

Comment: @Zoredache: it's a VPS indeed. I've used iptables on the same brand with no issue, but I'm starting to wonder if firehol perhaps choke on that with its modprobe actions. Thanks for the tip

Comment: Run `firehol debug`.  You'll see the individual commands.  You could try running things manually to find where it breaks.

Comment: I got an answer from my provider. They say I'm indeed probably missing some kernel modules to use firehol.